# Reading a file line by line and storing it into array do not work

Tags: c, fgets, arrays

What I want to do here is to read a text file containing phone numbers. For example:

```
01011112222
01027413565
01022223333
```

I want to store these phone numbers into an array for later use. Here below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   FILE *fl = NULL;
   char* phoneNums[10];

   int i = 0;
   fl = fopen("phoneNum.txt", "r");

   if(fl != NULL){
      char strTemp[14];

      while( !feof(fl) ){
        phoneNums[i] = fgets(strTemp, sizeof(strTemp), fl); 
        i++;
      }
      fclose(fl);
   }
   else{
      printf("File does not exist");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that whenever `fgets` is called, it returns the same reference of `strTemp`.

So every time it goes through the loop, it changes all value to the recent value in `phoneNums` array.

I tried to declare `char strTemp[14]` inside the `while` loop, but it didn't work.

At this point, what could I try to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to dynamically allocate an array of `char` arrays (unless you know the exact number of lines in the file).

Comment: what's gonna be the simple way for that? should I pre-process to count the number of phone numbers in a file??

Comment: I don't know Jun1987. You down-voted my answer (which works, by the way; I've tested it), so I removed it!!!

Comment: you see, I can't even do up-vote or down-vote since I have only 5 reputation.

Comment: No problem Jun1987. I'll add my answer (which checks the file size first and then preallocates the `phoneNums` array according to the number of lines).  You can try it, and I'll remove it later.

Comment: `while( !feof(fl) ) ...` is incorrect. Read more about the "EOF anti-pattern" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941 and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the below changes to get the exact result.

Change the strTemp variable to pointer variable.

```
 char *strTemp;
```

Inside while allocate the dynamic memory for the variable.

```
 strTemp=malloc(14);
 phoneNums[i]=fgets(strTemp,14,fl);
```

If you do like this it will create a new memory for each time so the value is stored in the different location. So it can't overwrite in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fl = NULL;
    char    phoneNums[3][14]; // you didn't allocate memory here. i am using static memory(for 3 phone numbers)
    int i = 0,j;
    fl = fopen("phoneNum.txt", "r");

    if(fl != NULL){
            char strTemp[14];

            while( fgets(strTemp, sizeof(strTemp), fl) ){
                    strcpy(phoneNums[i],strTemp); // you need to string copy function to copy one string to another string
                    i++;
            }
            fclose(fl);
    }
    else{
            printf("File does not exist");
    }
    for(j=0;j<i;j++) // i am printing the array content
            printf("%s\n",phoneNums[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the dynamic allocation of memory for `char *phoneNums[14];`

```
pnoneNums=(char **)malloc(14*n); // where n is the numbers of phone numbers
```